# Windows Forms Secondary Thread doesn't update field from Form class

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, database-connection

I am trying to use Background thread in my WF application to do operations on database,
but when I try to update field from my Form1 class within this background thread it doesn't throw any compile error, but it simply doesn't update it.

I am using Task.Run() with lambda expression and anonymous delegate, here is the code I am using

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = null;
         HashSet<string> CheckedEmails = new HashSet<string>();

 private HashSet<string> ListOfEmails()
        {
            CheckedEmails.Clear();

                   Queue<string> checkBoxes = new Queue<string>();
                   if (IT_checkbox.Checked)
                   {
                       checkBoxes.Enqueue(IT_checkbox.Text);
                   }
if (checkBoxes.Count() == 0)
                   {
                       return CheckedEmails;
                   }

                   Task.Run(() =>
                   {
                       //Thread.Sleep(10000);
                   SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                   while (checkBoxes.Count() != 0)
                   {
                       cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Select Email FROM Emails INNER JOIN Groups ON Emails.UniqueID=Groups.ID WHERE Groups.Grupa='{0}' ", checkBoxes.Dequeue());
                       SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                       while (dr.Read())
                       {
                           CheckedEmails.Add((string)dr["Email"]);
                       }
                       dr.Close();
                   }
               });
            return CheckedEmails;
        }

    }
```

In the end my field CheckedEmails isn't updated as it should, could you tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thank you in advance. Of course if I wanted to make DB operations in main thread this code works fine if we remove Task.Run(), but this is not what i want.

Comment: What do you mean by "*In the end*"? If this is at the end of the `ListOfEmails` method then this is expected because, most of the time, the task has not started yet. Apart from this, after a quick review, your code seems correct to me. To check simply popup a `MessageBox` each time you add an element to the HashSet. I think what you need is a way to notify your UI that you've finished retrieving the data, you could simply `Invoke` on the UI thread scheduler to raise an event.

Comment: @Pragmateek I am executing this function in another function to check if it works correctly private void Send_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           CheckedEmails= ListOfEmails();
            Task.WaitAll();
            MessageBox.Show(CheckedEmails.ElementAt(0));
        }

Comment: You're not waiting on your task so you'll have the same behavior. You could simply make your `ListOfEmails` method `async` and then wait on the returned `Task`, something like : `Task<HashSet<string>> checkedEmailsTask = ListOfEmails(); Task.WaitAll(checkedEmailsTask ); MessageBox.Show(checkedEmailsTask.Result.ElementAt(0));` If you're not using C# 5 then directly return a `Task<HashSet<string>>`. The best you could do is using **Rx** but if you're not familiar with it stick with the TPL, this will do the job too.